# How to check if remote participant disabled video (Twilio Programmable Video)

Tags: twilio, videochat

I've created peer to peer video chat using Twilio Programmable Video. I want to check if remote participant disabled video track and show avatar of that user for local participant in this case. How can I do it? Is there some event I can subscribe to know it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[trackDisabled event allows to check if remote participant disabled video](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.19.2/docs/RemoteParticipant.html#event:trackDisabled__anchor)

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You are looking for the [`RemoteParticipant`'s `trackUnpublished` event](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.19.2/docs/RemoteParticipant.html#event:trackUnpublished__anchor).

Comment: Looks like trackDisabled/trackEnabled events are what I need. Thanks for documentation link.